# date parameter as part of path uses default date conversion for open API codegen

Tags: java, openapi, swagger-codegen, openapi-generator

I am generating server code with spring boot. I am facing issue with date in path vs date in body.

If I use java8 config, my body dates are converted using jackson which uses yyyy-mm-dd

But if I put date in path parameter it uses default date conversion which expects date in dd/mm/yyyy format. It is very confusing for consumer.

As part of request body

```
    myDate:
      type: string
      format: date
      description: 'my date'
      example: '2018-02-05'
```

As part of path param

```
    - in: path
      name: my_date
      description: "my date"
      example: '2018-02-05'
      required: true
      schema:
        type: string
        format: date
```

as part of path parameter,  Here is debugging screenshot. LocalLisedDateTime[image]

[image: Debugging screenshots]

maven goal

```
                    <configuration>
                        <typeMappings>
                            <typeMapping>Double=java.math.BigDecimal</typeMapping>
                        </typeMappings>
                        <apiPackage>package.api</apiPackage>
                        <modelPackage>package.model</modelPackage>
                        <invokerPackage>package.internal</invokerPackage>
                        <inputSpec>
                            ${basedir}/src/main/resources/spec/thespec.yaml
                        </inputSpec>
                        <language>spring</language>
                        <withXml>true</withXml>
                        <output>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/swagger</output>
                        <generateApiTests>true</generateApiTests>
                        <ignoreFileOverride>${project.basedir}/.swagger-codegen-ignore</ignoreFileOverride>
                        <configOptions>
                            <sourceFolder>src/gen/java/main</sourceFolder>
                            <dateLibrary>java8</dateLibrary>
                            <withXml>true</withXml>
                            <interfaceOnly>true</interfaceOnly>
                            <!--swaggerDocketConfig>true</swaggerDocketConfig-->
                            <serializableModel>true</serializableModel>
                            <delegatePattern>true</delegatePattern>
                            <bigDecimalAsString>true</bigDecimalAsString>
                            <notNullJacksonAnnotation>true</notNullJacksonAnnotation>
                        </configOptions>
                    </configuration>
```

Comment: @tbatch Is there a way we can have same date format for body and url parameter ? like yyyy-mm-dd

Comment: Can you please share your generated code?  Both the parameter and the field should lookhave an annotation on them that sets the date time format.  They should both be  `@DateTimeFormat(iso = DateTimeFormat.ISO.DATE)`.  When you say it uses the default date conversion, are you saying it does this on serialization or deserialization, or both.  Is your ObjectMapper configured?  Have you registered the `JavaTimeModule` with it?  It appears that none of your problems have to do with the `openapi-generator` and have everything to do with your implementaiton of Jackson.